# Перемещение блока в зависимости от разрешения

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть меню полноэкранное по клику на кнопке, в мобильной версии в нем под пунктами меню модуль поиска(форма), а в десктопной версии поиск находится вообще в другом месте, в другом блоке ( не в меню). В связи с этим вопрос, как это реализовать? У меня два варианта:

1. Делать два поиска и в зависимости от разрешения отключать из поля зрения с помощью display
2. С помощью js чекать разрешение и перетаскивать поиск из одного места в другое

Может вы сталкивались с подобной задаче и реализовали вообще иначе, у меня больше нет идей

Ну и вопрос ещё, вообще это нормальная практика с помощью JS узнавать разрешение и в зависимости от данных делать манипуляции с элементами?

Comment: `position: absolute`

Comment: Вряд ли подойдёт, во-первых, мне не хочется выносить блок из потока, во-вторых, как потом выискивать, где он должен быть, будет что-то типа «top: 387px: left 891px;”

Comment: Вариант 1 совершенно нормальный и разумный.

Comment: Нормальная практика скорее заключается в том, чтобы при помощи [медиазапросов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) настраивать отображение элементов для мобильной и десктопной версии, если это не два разных продукта.

Comment: Первый вариант лучше чем скрипты, если можно не использовать скрипты - не используйте